# DNS propagation tools

Tags: dns, propagation

There is something wrong after a DNS change after a server migration, some users end up on the old server ip. E.g. if let my friend next door ping the address, he gets the 'old' ip. However, common propagation checks show me the correct ip on global dns servers. Is there a way to map this problem?

Answer (score -2, accepted):

This website does something like this:
https://www.whatsmydns.net/

A tool with more local detail would still be useful